# How to auto Add to a Many to Many table that created with C# EF Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I Created a Many to Many Relationship between two tables

Now whenever i add data to one table The table **MoviesHashTags** that was auto created by the DbContext stays empty.

Maybe I don't understand the connection between this two table, But is there a specific way to Add Data to one table and it will be added to the MoviesHashTags table too?

**Example:**

I'm adding a new HashTag to HashTags Table: This Hashtag Contain the **Movie Id**
When I'm Call **Add()** and **SaveChanges()** It's suppose to add the HashTag Id and the Movie Id to the MoviesHashTags Table.

***ATM this MoviesHashTags Table stays Empty***

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**TABLE Movies:**

```
[DataContract]
public class Movie 
{
    [DataMember]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    *
    *
    *
    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<HashTag> HashTagsCollection { get; set; }

public Movie()
{
    HashTagsCollection = new HashSet<HashTag>();
}
```

**TABLE HashTag:**

```
[DataContract]
public class HashTag
{
    [DataMember]
    public long HashTagId { get; set; }
    *
    *
    *
    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<Movie> MoviesCollection { get; set; }

    public HashTag()
    {
        MoviesCollection = new HashSet<Movie>();
    }
```

**DbContext:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().
    HasMany(c => c.HashTagsCollection).
    WithMany(p => p.MoviesCollection).
    Map(
        m =>
       {
        m.MapLeftKey("Id");
        m.MapRightKey("HashTagId");
        m.ToTable("MoviesHashTags");
        });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too bad that you don't show the code where you add the `HashTag`. But a way that should work is this:

```cs
var tag = new HashTag { /* setting properties */ };
var movie = db.Movies.Find(movieId);
movie.HashTagsCollection.Add(tag);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: So if I add an HashTag through the HashTagCollection it will add it to the MoviesHashTags table and the HashTags table too?